# python ruamel.yaml package, how to get header comment lines?

Tags: python, comments, ruamel.yaml

I want to get YAML file comments on header lines, like

```
# 11111111111111111
# 11111111111111111
# 22222222222222222
# bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
---
start:
....
```

And I used the `ca` attribute on the loaded data, butfound there are no these comments on it. Is there any other way to get these comments?

Comment: I would expect a YAML parser to ignore comments. Therefore, you could just open the file in the traditional way then check for the first significant character being #. It's going to be more complex if you want to extract comments that follow normal YAML syntax - e.g., "start: # This is the start"

Comment: @JCaesar `ruamel.yaml` (discl. I am the author) explicitly tries to preserve comments in its round-trip-mode, as it is in general a loss for a human who has to continue to work on a YAML document that is (also) loaded and dumped by a computer program.

Comment: Thank you all, I am considering to use traditional way to get these comments, and then insert them to other yaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (`ruamel.yaml==0.17.17`) the comments that occur
before the document start token (`---`) are not passed on from the
`DocumentStartToken` to the `DocumentStartEvent`, so these comments are
effectively lost during parsing.  Even if they were passed on, it is
non-trivial to preserve them as the `DocumentStartEvent` is silently
dropped during composition.

You can either put the comments after the end of directives indicator
(`---`) which allows you to get at the comments using the `.ca`
attribute without a problem, or remove that indicator altogether as it
is superfluous (at least in your example). Alternatively you will have to
write a small wrapper around the loader:

```
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

fn = pathlib.Path('input.yaml')

def load_with_pre_directives_comments(yaml, path):
    comments = []
    text = path.read_text()
    if '\n---\n' not in text and '\n--- ' not in text:
         return yaml.load(text), comments
    for line in text.splitlines(True):
        if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
            comments.append(line)
        elif line.startswith('---'):
            return yaml.load(text), comments
            break

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
data, comments = load_with_pre_directives_comments(yaml, fn)
print(''.join(comments), end='')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# 11111111111111111
# 11111111111111111
# 22222222222222222
# bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
---
start: 42
```